# bottle + gevent parallel support

Tags: python, bottle, gevent

I have a python bottle application, and use gevent server     `run(host=ip, port=8080, server="gevent")`    with `monkey.patch_all()`. The application will call API method on remote server then process result and return JSON result, like    `{"ret": "success", "code": "0", "message": null, "id": "00001"}`    . I use curl to test application, like    `curl http://10.10.10.10:8080/Check`    , it can return success. But when I try 2 client access at the same time, the first access return incomplete JSON result, just like     `{"ret": "success", "code": "0", "message": null, "id"`    , the second can return success. How to handle this parallel access?

In my application, it will received some parameter such as    `id`     , then use those parameters will create class,  when client access at the same time,  those variables value are overrided.

Comment: Monkey patching pyCurl is not enough. Have a look at [gevent-curl](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent-curl) or use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) alternatively.

Comment: I just use curl to simulator client access and test my application, not use curl in my application to visit API, do I need use gevent-curl?

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using the built in method for bottle's gevent.  The reason is that monkey patch should be run as soon as possible.

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn as gspawn, joinall
monkey.patch_all()
import bottle
from app import appRoute
from client import clientRoute
from main import mainRoute
from api import apiRoute
from sandbox import sandboxRoute
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
botapp = bottle.app()
for route in (mainRoute, appRoute, clientRoute, apiRoute, sandboxRoute):
    botapp.merge(route)
botapp = SessionMiddleware(botapp, beaker_opts)
port = 80
WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(port)), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler).serve_forever()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Are you claiming the the OP's problem is caused by monkey patching too late? He doesn't state when he is calling `patch_all`, so I'm not sure how you could conclude that.

Comment: With the lack of information in the main post, how can you say this isn't the right answer?  I am building off of 10 years of experience in resolving these issues for customers, what are you using as your basis for criticism?